# Блоки <div> в колонку,или друг под другом

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Такая проблема: сделал лого в углу сайта,и объединил с другим горизонтальным блоком `<div>`.

Теперь когда я хочу сделать снизу под логом еще один блок, он у меня получается не от края, а с отступом.

```css
.header {
  color: #22D99F;
  background-color: #052230;
  border: 3px solid #6593E1;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.news {
  margin-right: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #6593E1;
  border: 5px solid #382C49;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: #D2C2E1;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.news:hover {
  background-color: #78527E;
  color: lime;
}

.hood {
  float: left;
}

.lab {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #052230;
  border: 5px solid #382C49;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 200px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lab hood kek">
  <a href="сайт.html">
    <IMG src="net.png" border=0 width=250 alt="CS:GO">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="header hood">
  <div class="news">
    <B>Новости</B>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <B>Матчи</B>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <B>Статистика</B>
  </div>
  <div class="news">
    <B>Турниры</B>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu kek">
  Текст...
</div>
```

В конечном итоге должно получиться так:

[image: Итог]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там у вас жесть в css - в общем есть теги которые уже строчные и ссылка относится к ним

Вот примерно то что вам было надо исходя из скриншота

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.aside {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 250px;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="">
  <nav>
    <a href="">Пункт 1</a>
    <a href="">Пункт 2</a>
    <a href="">Пункт 3</a>
    <a href="">Пункт 4</a>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="aside">
  Офигенно важный текст
</div>
```